# Reference Request: Convergence of Series over Integer Lattice

Tags: convergence-divergence, reference-request, integer-lattices

I am writing a school paper on Modular forms, and I want to use the following result without including a proof, since it is not directly related to my main topic.

> For $s>0$, $d \in \mathbb{N}$, the series $\sum\limits_{v\in\mathbb{Z}^d\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{{\left \| v \right \|}^s}$ converges iff $s>d$.

However I am struggling to find a good reference for this to include in my paper. Can anyone point me to a book/paper that proves this?

Comment: Compare with the corresponding integral?

Comment: See Theorem B.1 (starting on page 29) in https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/CTNTmodularforms.pdf for which your formulation uses almost identical notation already. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove the convergence of the sum over tuples of nonzero integers.

$$
\sum_{v\in (\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})^d} \frac1{\|v\|^s} \ \ \ \tag{1}
$$

Apply the AM-GM inequality, we have for $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_d)$, 
$$
\frac1{\|v\|^2} \leq \frac d{(v_1^2v_2^2\cdots v_d^2)^{1/d} }
$$
The $s/2$-th powers of these satisfy
$$
\frac1{\|v\|^s}\leq \frac{d^{s/2}}{|v_1v_2\cdots v_d|^{s/d}}
$$
If $s>d$, then the sum $(1)$ converges by comparison test.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your answer, but I actually know a proof. I was just asking for a book/paper reference to cite in my paper, so that I don't have to include the proof because the paper is pretty long already and this result is not very related with the rest of the paper (it's just a technical lemma).

Comment: That's great. I think no one would mind if you don't include the proof. This result is widely accepted and used in the literatures about modular forms. But, I realized that my proof should also include divergence when $s\leq d$. Since you know the proof, I will pass this.